# mysql show records by week

Tags: mysql, database

hi i have a orders table i want to run a query that will return no of orders in last 4 weeks if there is no order's in any week it should say 0 orders what i am doing is not working

```
ID | order_Date | amount
1  | 2011-03-01  | 10
2  | 2011-03-01  | 50
3  | 2011-02-24  | 60

select sum(amount) as total from orders group by WEEK(order_date,INTERVAL 3 Week)
```

thanks

Comment: itried YEARWEEK but its just showing me single record then

Comment: do you know how a "where clause" works? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select monday,monday + interval 6 day as sunday,coalesce(a.total,0) as total from (
select curdate() - 
interval weekday(curdate()) day - interval tmp.digit * 1 week as monday             
from (
select 0 as digit union all 
select 1 union all 
select 2 union all 
select 3
) as tmp ) as t 
left join (     select 
        week(order_date) as nweek, 
        sum(amount) as total
        from orders
        where order_date
        between 
        curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day - interval 3 week and
        curdate() + interval 6 - weekday(curdate()) day
        group by nweek order by null
       ) as a
on week(monday) = a.nweek   
group by a.nweek
order by monday desc
```

Results:

```
+------------+------------+--------+
| monday     | sunday     | total  |
+------------+------------+--------+
| 2011-02-28 | 2011-03-06 | 834312 |
| 2011-02-21 | 2011-02-27 | 818334 |
| 2011-02-14 | 2011-02-20 | 824032 |
| 2011-02-07 | 2011-02-13 | 695021 |
+------------+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

let's look at the language you're using:

> that will return no of orders in last 4 weeks

here you're declaring a condition under which rows should count towards the total sum. such conditions are expressed as "where" clauses in sql. so our "where" clause should in this case compare the date of the order, and see that it's within a certain interval.

now the question is if 4 weeks in your case means "this week and the three weeks before this week", or "today and 27 days before this day". it's easiest to use the "27 days" reasoning, so i'll use that! so, our criteria is that the order date (found in column order_Date) should be **after** (or larger than) a day that's 27 days before today. this means we need to calculate a day that's 27 days before this day. we do this with the function SUBDATE and the function CURDATE. here's the "where" clause only:

```
WHERE
    order_Date > SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 27 DAY)
```

this way we can find all the orders we want to add together. here's the query that lists all the orders we want:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    order_Date > SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 27 DAY);
```

now we need to add them up into one result line! to do this, we need to group the resulting lines into one, and then sum up all the amounts. but "group by" only groups up lines where the chosen column to group by has the same value. and there's no guarantee that  there will be any such column in the lines. so we'll create one in the SELECT part of the query.

```
SELECT
    amount,
    1 AS column_to_group_by
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    order_Date > SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 27 DAY);
```

now we can group by the column column_to_group_by.

```
SELECT
    amount,
    1 AS column_to_group_by
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    order_Date > SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 27 DAY)
GROUP BY
    column_to_group_by;
```

the result is now utterly useless, since it's only showing the amount of the first line of the table. but we can now sum up all the amounts, and this way get the answer we want!

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount),
    1 AS column_to_group_by
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    order_Date > SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 27 DAY)
GROUP BY
    column_to_group_by;
```

i hope this explanation will help you adopt the problem solving methodology applied here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(amount) as total from orders 
where 
order_date between date_sub(now(), interval 4 week) and 
date_sub(now(), interval 3 week)
union
select sum(amount) as total from orders 
where 
order_date between date_sub(now(), interval 3 week) and 
date_sub(now(), interval 2 week)
union
select sum(amount) as total from orders 
where 
order_date between date_sub(now(), interval 2 week) and 
date_sub(now(), interval 1 week)
union
select sum(amount) as total from orders 
where 
order_date between date_sub(now(), interval 1 week) and now();
```